# jQuery onClick Event not firing

Tags: jquery

I have a click event for an `a` pagination list

Its not firing.

```
$(".pagination-page").click(function()
{
    //event.preventDefault();

    var page = $(this).val();

    $('#search-results-display').load('includes/search.php?query=<? echo $_SESSION['search_term']; ?>&page=' + page);
});
```

PHP While loop generating the pagination (only the generation of the pagination not the rest of it. The SQL query is working, that has been tested

```
while ($tmpPageCnt > 0) 
{
    $retvar .= '<li class="active"><a href="#" class="pagination-page">'.$tmpPage.'</a></li>';
}

return $retvar;
```

Please could you shed some light as to why it's not

Comment: Any errors in the console? Post the relevant HTML as well

Comment: There's no errors in the console and bare will be will do

Comment: So at time you are binding event, do elements exist in DOM?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the event handler you posted.  Maybe there's no `".pagination-page"` element when this code executes?  You can confirm this by debugging the JavaScript code in the browser.

Comment: They don't appear until after the user has submitted a search query - So would I need to load it in with the search results?

Comment: Related: [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dynamically creating it, I suppose you need to use event-delegation

```
$(document).on('click', ".pagination-page", function() {
    var page = $(this).text();
    $('#search-results-display').load('includes/search.php?query=<? echo $_SESSION['search_term']; ?>&page=' + page);
});
```

And since it is `<a>` you should be using `.text()` as anchors don't have values.

Comment: Could you give an example below this issue showing what's needed to be done

Comment: Quotes for PHP and JavaScript strings won't necessarily clash with each other. They're parsed separately at different times.

Comment: That's what I thought which is why I didn't escape any of it

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne I don't know about php, but give it a try and note that `.text()`

Comment: As I've said on the other answers, the event itself is not getting called, so whether its `.text()` or not the actual `.click` function is not getting called

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne check out now

Comment: What is the difference between what it was and what it is now?

Answer (score -1):

Changing `.val();` to `.html();` should solve the problem

Comment: The actual event itself is not getting fired, so this, at this stage, is not an issue (will keep in mind though)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne - my apologies, as I was making a mock-up on my end, it appeared to not be fireing either. However it was just a case of nothing being returned by the .val(). I [wrongly] assumed that what corrected things in my mock-up was the entirety of your issue.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams - I thought it was the answer to the question (see my reply to Zach), however it seems I was mistaken.